# Deploying two projects on different ports in Apache Tomcat for Netbeans IDE

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to deploy two (service and a client) on the same Tomcat server. It ends up throwing the error "Port already in use". Is there any place where I can configure which project uses which port while deploying or both the projects uses different ports?

Comment: Are you able to deploy one application with out error?  If Yes then It should be ports that your applications trying to open

Comment: I am able to run one project successfully. I do not follow what you are trying to convey. Could you please elaborate a little ?

Comment: Then your applications might be opening the ports, you need to configure different ports in your applications not in the Tomcat server